# How to make an enemy stop firing bullets at player when there is a wall between them

Tags: game-maker

I have three object, obj_player, obj_enemy, obj_wall. Now, I have this code from gmc forums.

```
shoot_cooldown -= 1;                                 //Lower the shooting cooldown timer
if (shoot_cooldown < 0) then shoot_cooldown = 0     //Prevents timer from counting down           further than 0.
target_distance = distance_to_object(obj_player);    //Distance to the player from enemy.

if (target_distance < 64)                 //If player within the range of enemy
{
//image_angle = point_direction(x,y,obj_player.x,obj_player.y);      //Enemy faces the player.
if (shoot_cooldown == 0)                                      //If enemy can shoot (cooldown ready)
    {
    bullet = instance_create(x,y,obj_bullet);                  //Create a bullet relative to enemy
    bullet.direction = point_direction(x,y,obj_player.x,obj_player.y);   //Shoot it towards player
    bullet.speed = 3;                                           //Give it speed
    shoot_cooldown = 50;    //Set the new cooldown time between low and high thresholds.
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. However, the obj_player and obj_enemy have the dimensions of 64x64. I have in my code that if the player's distance between the enemy is equal or below 64pix, enemy will fire a bullet. Now the obj_wall has the dimension of 32x32. If the player is on the other side of the wall, the enemy must not fire a bullet since enemy "can't detect" the player. But the enemy still fires a bullet because the player is within 64 pix. I wonder if there is a workaround in making the enemy stop firing if there is a wall between them. Thanks for those who will reply. I know there is gmc forums I'm hoping someone can also help me here.

Comment: i think you need to create a function that determines if a wall is between, say `is_wall_between` then add that into your 'if' statement like `if (target_distance < 64 && ! is_wall_between() )`

Comment: by the title - do not give them a gun in the first place. But if you are American that is not an option as they like to arm the world - just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collision_line` between `obj_enemy` and `obj_player`, like

```
if target_distance < 64 and collision_line(x, y, obj_player.x, obj_player.y, obj_wall, false, true) == noone
{
    // shoot
}
```

for more perfect you can check line between enemy and every corner of the player